# Calculating the area

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace area
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             double basse;
             double height;                   

             Console.WriteLine("Enter your base length: ");
             basse = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

             Console.WriteLine( "Enter the height: ");
             height = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());                    

             double area = Program.triangleArea(basse, height);
             Console.WriteLine("Your area is {0:f3}", area);
             Console.ReadLine();                    
             double pryrmid = Program.pyramidVolume( triangleArea);
             Console.WriteLine(" Pyramid Volume is {0:f3}" , pryrmid);                                       
        }

        public static double triangleArea(double basse, double height)
        {
            return (0.5 * basse) * height;
        }             
        public static double pyramidVolume (double triangleArea)                
        {
            return (1/3) * triangleArea;                
        }        
    }                       
}
```

I'm trying the calculate the volume of a pryamid using the methods ive defined.

I keep getting the error

> Argument '1': cannot convert from 'method group' to 'double' (CS1503)
>   - \vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\WS_6_D\WS_6_D\Program.cs:28,57

and

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'area.Program.pyramidVolume(double)' has some invalid arguments
>   (CS1502) - \vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\SharpDevelop
>   Projects\WS_6_D\WS_6_D\Program.cs:28,34

I was wondering if someone could help me get on the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `triangleArea` in
`double pryrmid = Program.pyramidVolume( triangleArea);` is not a variable, hence it points to the static method.

Try `double pryrmid = Program.pyramidVolume( area);` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is expecting something it can evaluate to a double, but you supply the name of a function (`triangleArea`).

Instead, you probably want to pass the `area` you calculated previously.

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant to say

```
double pryrmid = Program.pyramidVolume(area);
```

instead of

```
double pryrmid = Program.pyramidVolume( triangleArea);
```

`triangleArea` is your method, you used `area` as your result value.